# How can I dynamically add rows to my form?(Django)

Tags: jquery, html, django

I have a Model which connects to a Form. You can assume it is a very simple model with 1 attribute.

```
class Past_Location(models.Model):

    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to let the user be able to add more rows to the form via a button. So that's why I reflect this model to a formset:

```
LocationFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(
    Past_Location,
    fields='__all__',
    extra=1,
    widgets={
        'location': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter Location Name here'
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Here is the button creation to add more rows.

```
            <div class="input-group">
              {{ form.name }}
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <input type="text" name="name" value="">
                <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

views.py

```
def form_name_view(request):
    form = forms.NewPatientForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = NewPatientForm(request.GET or None)
        formset = LocationFormSet(queryset=Past_Location.objects.none())
        print("Hey1")
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print("Hey2")
        form = NewPatientForm(request.POST)
        formset = LocationFormSet(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            patient_info = form.save()
            for loc in formset:

                location = loc.save(commit=False)
                location.save()
                location.patient.add(patient_info)
                location.save()

            return index(request)
        else:
            print('Error Form Invalid')

    return render(request, 'first_app/form_page.html', {'form':form,'formset':formset})
```

I thought the class "add-form-row" would be enough to add more rows dynamically but it was not. So I wanted to follow some examples and use jquery to add more rows. However, since my form is reflected from a model, I don't know how to access and add a new row via jquery. I wanted to post a MVP however the project is too complex with too many necessary files. So I would want to know what is the standard way of interacting with modelForms through jquery?

Comment: Front side is a job for JS, not Django.

Comment: But I think, you use the variable names from view.py to access from jquery.